# Jokes about language confusion in Spanish?

Tags: gramática, cultura-de-masas, humor

In English, I love things like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_JmZau9aMa4&t=134s) and [this](https://thesavvyredpen.com/dangling-misplaced-modifiers/):

> Driving home late the other night, a deer suddenly appeared in our
> headlights.

> I wonder if the deer had a hard time getting a driver’s license. Ba-dum cha!

Jokes about language being confusing.

Can anyone recommend things like this in Spanish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo "**La tesis de Nancy**" de Ramón J. Sender. Es una divertida obra en español que leí hace muchos años y que aconsejo para cualquier nivel.

La nota introductoria dice;

> NOTA PREVIA
>
> Mi amiga Betsy tiene una prima estudiante de español que ha ido a
> España para obtener un grado universitario. Betsy me ha enseñado una
> carta de su prima, fechada en Alcalá de Guadaira (Sevilla). Creí al
> verla que valía la pena traducirla. Después le he pedido más cartas, y
> las he traducido también.

[image]

https://www.academia.edu/7425949/La_tesis_de_nancy